# View start time of Matlab timer object

Tags: matlab, time, timer

How do you view and amend the start time of a timer object in Matlab?  The closest I can get is the "StartDelay" element of the timer object :

```
all_timers = get(timerfind);
```

where each element of the returned structure array is one timer object.  The various elements of the structure are (for example):

```
   AveragePeriod: NaN
        BusyMode: 'drop'
        ErrorFcn: ''
   ExecutionMode: 'singleShot'
   InstantPeriod: NaN
            Name: 'timer-1'
ObjectVisibility: 'on'
          Period: 1
         Running: 'on'
      StartDelay: 7.200175000000000e+003
        StartFcn: ''
         StopFcn: ''
             Tag: ''
   TasksExecuted: 0
  TasksToExecute: Inf
        TimerFcn: @myFcn
            Type: 'timer'
        UserData: []
```

According to:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html

"StartDelay" is: **Number greater than or equal to 0 that specifies the delay, in seconds, between the start of the timer and the first execution of the function specified in TimerFcn.**

but unless I know when the timer object was started/created/initiated, the StartDelay is no real help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `startFun` can be used to evaluate a function on timer start, which could store the start time in the `userData` of the timer

#### Most simple

Define a function such as;

```
function myStartFcn(hTimer,~)
hTimer.UserData = now; 
end
```

and set this to be the startFcn of the timer

```
hTimer = timer();
hTimer.StartFcn = @myStartFcn
```

#### A better? example

`userData` is a useful field we may want to use it for many things, in which case making it a structure and setting this as a field would be better. also `now` gives datenum format which may not be ideal, `clock` is another possibility;

```
function myStartFcn(hTimer,~)
    tempStruct = hTimer.UserData;
    tempStruct.startTime = clock;
    hTimer.UserData = tempStruct;
end
```

Also it may be worth clearing this when the timer is stopped and storing the last run time in seconds

```
function myStopFcn(hTimer,~)
    tempStruct = hTimer.UserData;
    tempStruct.lastRunTime = etime(clock,tempStruct.startTime)
    tempStruct.startTime = []
    hTimer.UserData = tempStruct;
end
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you!  It's remarkable that the start time is not "baked in" to the timer object in the first place.  Anyway, your suggestion is an excellent work around.